# Removing the shared colorbar in Xarray subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray

I'm trying to fine-tune my subplot by making a shared color bar using the high-level plotting functions of Xarrays. At the moment my plot looks [image] and I want to make a common color bar and fix the yaxis so that only 1st subplot y-axis has ticks and labels. The code I used to plot this looks like this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(14,10))
Var1_monthly_clim_N.plot(ax=ax1,vmin=6, vmax=14, cmap='jet');

Var2_monthly_clim_S.plot(ax=ax2, vmin=6, vmax=14, cmap='jet', yticks=[]);
## why is yticks removing ticks from both axis
## Var1 and Var 2 have similiar dimensions
Var1
>><xarray.DataArray 'R_metric' (month: 12, lat: 1, lon: 720)>
array([[[ 9.899495,  9.942897, ...,  9.814826,  9.856807]],

   [[ 9.578215,  9.610594, ...,  9.514423,  9.546191]],

   ...,

   [[11.974784, 12.019565, ..., 11.886591, 11.930419]],

   [[10.237672, 10.285891, ..., 10.142638, 10.189836]]])
Coordinates:
* lon      (lon) float32 -180.0 -179.5 -179.0 -178.5 ... 178.5 179.0 179.5
* month    (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Dimensions without coordinates: lat
```

I'm not the most proficient with python plotting and I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995116/7763326) idea of plotting using imshow to try

```
img1 = Var1.data
img2 = Var2.data 
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(img1, vmin=6, vmax=14, cmap='jet', aspect='auto')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(img2, vmin=6, vmax=14, cmap='jet', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar()
>>TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

How can I do this quickly using the highlevel plotting functions of xarray, that is, not extracting the data into numpy arrays and making meshgrid and all for the plot?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've never used xarray, so I may be wrong, but, [from looking at the documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.plot.pcolormesh.html#xarray.plot.pcolormesh), it looks like you could pass `add_colorbar=False` to you first `plot()` call to suppress the creation of one of the colorbar.

As for your ylabel problem, you have requested to have a shared y-axis, so if you remove the labels from one, you also remove them from the other. Interestingly, `plt.subplots(..., sharey=True)` should already have set up things so that only the leftmost graph(s) have y-labels, and their hidden in the other Axes. If `xarray`'s `plot()` is messing with that, then your best bet is to remove `sharey=True` and ensure that the limits are the same by hand (using `ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim()` for instance.)

Comment: That worked well, thank you. Any ideas why plt.imshow didn't work? Here, my data is 3-D in the form of Z = f(X,Y) as there is only one Lat dimension but maybe because of that the shape of my array is 12x1x720 and maybe because of that function is thinking that the dataset is 4-D ?

Comment: I found the answer to the above comment. Xarray plotting is internally calling a function to squeeze the dimensions. That's why the plt.pcolormesh() worked.

Comment: Just removing the colorbar like that doesn't work so well, because then the images end up with different aspect ratios, or otherwise sized differently.