# Set output range of matplotlib - imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a project I'm working on I have created two sets of data which is made from a function that takes two input and returns a 3rd. I am currently using a matplotlib imshow graph to show the data. As one of the data sets contains far higher values than the other data set so I was hoping to set a range for both meaning the colours would represent the same value across the two charts. Is there a good way to do this? thankyou
Here is the code I am currently using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import numpy as np

with open("multi_testing\out_put\\bit_shift.txt","r") as f:
    n = json.loads(f.read())
    n = n[0]
    inp = np.array(n)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(inp)
    ax.invert_yaxis()

    ax.set_title("bit shifting")
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

and here are the two data sets:

[[[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],[11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11],[15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15],[19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19],[23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23],[27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27],[31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31],[35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35],[39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39],[43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43],[47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47]]]

and

[[[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42],[10,19,26,28,33,35,35,37,40,42,42]]]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imshow subplots with the same colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989917/imshow-subplots-with-the-same-colorbar)

Comment: Does my reply answer your question? If so, could you mark it as so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vmin` and `vmax` for this while using `ax.imshow()`. For example:

```
im = ax.imshow(inp, vmin=0, vmax=50)
```